# Tkinter - Child window object instantiates but its animation loop will not run - Why is this?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Currently I have created my main window (my parent window) which acts as the main menu, there are buttons which open up the relevant window.

What I want to happen is when the user clicks the PLAY GAME button the game window will be instantiated and open, and the animation loop ('move_player' method) will start.

Currently when the button is pressed, the game_window object is instantiated but when the object's 'move_player' method is called, it doesn't recognise the object and thus the animation loop does not continue. A run time error occurs.

Here is the relevant pieces of code:

```
import sqlite3, os, random, sys

from tkinter import *
passcode = 0
users_db = sqlite3.connect("users_db.db")
class Main():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("800x850")
        self.master.title("MENU")
        root.configure(bg = "green")

        self.button_play = Button(self.master, text = "Play Game", bg = "aquamarine", command = self.Instantiate_Game)
        self.button_play.place(x = 350, y = 325)
        self.button_instructions = Button(self.master, text = "Instructions", bg = "aquamarine", command = self.Instantiate_Instructions)
        self.button_instructions.place(x = 347, y = 355)
        self.button_scoreboard = Button(self.master, text = "Scoreboard", bg = "aquamarine", command = self.Instantiate_Scoreboard)
        self.button_scoreboard.place(x = 348, y = 385)
        self.button_settings = Button(self.master, text = "Settings", bg = "aquamarine", command = self.Instantiate_Settings)
        self.button_settings.place(x = 357, y = 415)
        self.button_exit = Button(self.master, text = "Exit", bg = "aquamarine", command = self.Exit)
        self.button_exit.place(x = 368, y = 445)

    def Exit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def Instantiate_Game(self):
        game_win = Toplevel(self.master)
        game_window = Game(game_win)
        game_window.move_player()
        game_win.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', arrow_release)
        game_win.bind_all('<KeyPress>', set_player_direct)

    def Instantiate_Instructions(self):
        instruction_win = Toplevel(self.master)
        instruction_window = Instructions(instruction_win)

    def Instantiate_Scoreboard(self):
        scoreboard_win = Toplevel(self.master)
        scoreboard_window = Scoreboard(scoreboard_win)
        scoreboard_win.configure(background = "green")

    def Instantiate_Settings(self):
        global setting_win
        setting_win = Toplevel(self.master)
        setting_window = Settings(setting_win)
        setting_win.configure(bg = "green")


    def Instantiate_Login(self):

        login_win = Toplevel(self.master)
        login_window = Login(login_win)
        login_window.Focus()
        #login_win.overrideredirect(1)
        login_win.configure(background = "blue")

class Game():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("800x850")
        self.master.title("GAME")
        self.canvas_game = Canvas(self.master, width = 800, height = 850, bg = "green")
        self.canvas_game.place(x = 0, y= 0)
        #Creating player rect
        px = 10
        py = 10
        pa = 40
        pb = 40
        player_rect_spawn_coords = [px, py, pa, pb]
        self.player_rect = self.canvas_game.create_rectangle(player_rect_spawn_coords, fill = "blue", outline = "blue")
        self.player_x_velo = 5
        self.player_y_velo = 0
        self.arrow_down = False

        #Set players direction

    def set_player_direct(event):
        self.arrow_down = True
        if event.keysym == "Left":
            self.player_x_velo = -5
            self.player_y_velo = 0
        if event.keysym == "Right":
            self.player_x_velo = 5
            self.player_y_velo = 0
        if event.keysym == "Up":
            self.player_x_velo = 0
            self.player_y_velo = -5
        if event.keysym == "Down":
            self.player_x_velo = 0
            self.player_y_velo = 5

    def arrow_release(event):
        self.arrow_down = False

    def check_contact_boarders(self):
        coordinate_player = self.canvas_game.coords(self.player_rect)
        if coordinate_player[0] < 0:
            self.player_x_velo = 5
            arrow_down = True
        if coordinate_player[0] > 800:
            self.player_x_velo = - 5
            arrow_down = True
        if coordinate_player[1] < 0:
            self.player_y_velo = 5
            arrow_down = True
        if coordinate_player[1] > 850:
            self.player_y_velo = - 5
            arrow_down = True

    #Player movement
    def move_player(self):
        Game.check_contact_boarders(self)
        self.canvas_game.move(self.player_rect, self.player_x_velo, self.player_y_velo)
        root.after(33, Game.move_player(self))

root = Tk()
main_window = Main(root)
#main_window.Instantiate_Login()


root.mainloop()
```

Run time error:

```
File "<module1>", line 115, in move_player
  File "<module1>", line 113, in move_player
  File "<module1>", line 97, in check_contact_boarders
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2162, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2160, in <listcomp>
    return [getdouble(x) for x in
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

This line "*File "<module1>", line 115, in move_player*" is repeated many times (in the error) before the error message you see above

Comment: what is the runtime error?

Comment: runtime error added to post - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your functions incorrectly. Instead of `Game.method(self,  ...)` you need to be calling `self.method(...)`.

Second, your use of `after` is incorrect. You're calling the function *immediately*, and then passing the result to `after`. To use `after` you must pass a *reference* to the function.

For example:

```
def move_player(self):
    self.check_contact_borders()
    root.after(33, self.move_player)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this has solved the issue I stated. The animation now works! Thanks again :)